# clone() method doesn't work like it should be

Tags: java

I have problem. My clone() method from Cloneable Interface dosen't work like it should be.

I have something like this:

```
        Figure cTest = new Square("Square", 0, 0, new Color(100, 20, 40), new Color(100, 20, 40), 4);
        Figure cTest1 = cTest;
        Figure cTest2 = (Figure)cTest.clone();

        System.out.println(cTest == cTest1); //result true 
        System.out.println(cTest == cTest2); //result false
        System.out.println(cTest.equals(cTest2)); // result false, but it should be true
```

I implemented Cloneable interface in Figure class, and overrode clone() method with `return super.clone()` signature.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need to see your `clone` and `equals` method in full.

Comment: I assume you haven't overridden `equals`, in which case the default implementation is used; this is equivalent to `return this == other`.

Comment: `doesn't work like it should be` is a really vague description of the problem.

Comment: Basically what @BoristheSpider said. If you haven't overridden the `equals` method to compare something like shape and color or some other attributes, it's going to use `Objects` `equals` method which just compares references, which they won't be the same.

Comment: @tnw I would say it's less a description of _a problem_ but more a definition of the concept of "problem".

Comment: Ok it is true. I have not overriden 'equals' method. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user6158005 Make sure that you override `hashCode` as well. There are loads of really good answers on SO about overriding these methods, plus your IDE can generate them both for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` compares if the given references pointing the same object. In your example `cTest` and `cTest1` pointing the same object, `cTest2` pointing the cloned object. And keep in mind that if you did not override the `equals` it is using `==` by default to compare the given objects. So all of the results you provide, are very normal to happen.